# Microsoft CRM Default error page (hosted app), is there any way to change it

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, custom-errors

Look and feel for the normal error page of Microsoft CRM 2011 is not good, is there any way to change or override it from the application to have a better look.
*replace it with Asp page as ex and put Asp path into some where to be shown instead of normal one
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you thought in accepting correct answer for your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so, as far as I know there is no supported way to customise that area of CRM.

The only way I can think of doing that is to directly edit the application files but that is unsupported and there is a chance you will loose changes when CRM updates are applied.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.... you mean that when we could change the system web.config by adding custom error page like an asp application it will fire problems with any updates for CRM??

Comment: Probably, its not supported to change the CRM application files, so you might be able to get it to work, but future updates might break your changes or break CRM. Its a bit on an unknown, in all honesty I wouldn't bother changing it, seems like an unnecessary change.